# Bootstrap Adding Margin to Centered Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 columns that have height 100%. The text is centered in the middle of these columns with margin-left 0.

```html
   <div class='container-fluid'>
            <div class="row mh-100">
                <div class='col-lg-6 ml-2 mh-100'>
                    <div class='position-absolute top-50 translate-middle-y'>
                            <p> text 1 here </p>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                <div class='col-lg-6 mh-100'>
                    <div class='position-absolute top-50 translate-middle-y'>
                        <p> text 2 here </p>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to add a bit of margin-left to col1 but `ml-2` doesn't do it. How should I implement this? Thanks.

```
 _____________________________________________
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|-->text1              |text2                 |    
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you need this CSS rule:

```
.ml-2 > div > p{
    margin-left: 5px; //set this value to what you want
}
```

**UPDATE:** `position-absolute` class is conflicting with `ml-2` in your case

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some height in col div, like:

```
.col-lg-6 {
    height:50px;
}
```

Use some custom class instead of .col-lg-6

Answer (score -1):

you can us &nbsp before the starting of the paragraph tag of text1.